# Eutectic Phase Diagram of Al-Si Analysis

Tags: phase, metallurgy, precipitation, alloy, eutectic

[image]

Hello,
How can I know from this phase diagram:
1. The composition of the alloy Al-Si that allows precipitation to occure?
2. The range of temperatures where the Al-Si is soluble?
3. The range of temperatures in which precipitation can take place?

Regarding the 1st and 2nd question- I assume that 1.6%wt Si at 557 degrees Celsius is the max solubility limit of this alloy, and that you can't have precipitation if there are higher percentages of Si in the aluminium.
But what about precipitation temperatures? Which conditions allow having precipitation?

Comment: Please clarify a bit about the precipitation.

Comment: precipitation=age hardening